# Forward ref through React Router's withRouter HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to manage to focus on a component that I've wrapped with withRouter. However, when I give the component a ref, I get the a warning about assigning a ref to a stateless component. I'm assuming this is because the ref is being attached to the withRouter HOC and not my component, as it is stateful. My general set up looks like this:

```
// InnerComponent.js

class InnerComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

export default withRouter(InnerComponent);

// App.js

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }

render() {
    return (
       <Router>
           <InnerComponent ref={this.myRef}>
       </Router>
    );
}
```

I see this question has been asked before, but never answered. I'm new to React so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm fairly sure what I need is here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter, in the wrappedComponentRef section of the withRouter docs, but I don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: If you are not use the state in the component, it will be consider a `stateless component`. So in react you can't create reference for stateless component.

Comment: @kumark I do use the state in my component, just didn't include it for my example. My issue is that the withRouter HOC has been written for me and so I can't forward my ref through it as shown in the React docs.

Answer (score 10):

Based on @Ranjith Kumar answer I came up with the following solution that:

- Is a bit shorter/simpler (no need for class component or `withRef` option)
- Plays a bit better in tests and dev tools

```js
const withRouterAndRef = Wrapped => {
  const WithRouter = withRouter(({ forwardRef, ...otherProps }) => (
    <Wrapped ref={forwardRef} {...otherProps} />
  ))
  const WithRouterAndRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <WithRouter {...props} forwardRef={ref} />
  ))
  const name = Wrapped.displayName || Wrapped.name
  WithRouterAndRef.displayName = `withRouterAndRef(${name})`
  return WithRouterAndRef
}
```

Usage is the same:

```js
// Before
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
// After
export default withRouterAndRef(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 6):

HOC component to forward inner component refs with `withRouter` HOC

```
const withRouterInnerRef = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class InnerComponentWithRef extends React.Component {    
        render() {
            const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
            return <WrappedComponent {...rest} ref={forwardRef} />;
        }
    }

    const ComponentWithRef = withRouter(InnerComponentWithRef, { withRef: true });

    return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return <ComponentWithRef {...props} forwardRef={ref} />;
      });
}
```

Usage

```
class InnerComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

export default withRouterInnerRef(InnerComponent);
```

Comment: I am stunned I am providing the first upvote for this solution. This totally works! I spent a good couple of hours trying and failing with solutions having hundreds of votes on S/O. Give this solution a whirl ladies & gents!

Comment: They have introduced new prop `wrappedComponentRef `, this might help.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/withRouter.js#L14

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have done this way! this will work for sure

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

//Just copy and add this withRouterAndRef HOC

const withRouterAndRef = (WrappedComponent) => {
class InnerComponentWithRef extends React.Component {    
      render() {
          const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
          return <WrappedComponent {...rest} ref={forwardRef} />;
      }
  }
  const ComponentWithRouter = withRouter(InnerComponentWithRef, { withRef: true });
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      return <ComponentWithRouter {...props} forwardRef={ref} />;
    });
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

//export using withRouterAndRef

export default withRouterAndRef (MyComponent)
```

Comment: This is awesome. I built upon your solution to add `displayName` capability to it. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `React.forwardRef` (https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) like this:

```
// InnerComponent.js

class InnerComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

export default withRouter(InnerComponent);

// App.js

const InnerComponentWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <InnerComponent ref={ref} props={props} />);

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }

render() {
    return (
       <Router>
           <InnerComponentWithRef ref={this.myRef}>
       </Router>
    );
}
```

> Note: Untested code!

Comment: I still have the same issue. I don't think React Router supports the Forwarding API yet: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6056.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can use `withRef` option available while exporting the component.

See the below sample to export

```
    // InnerComponent.js

    class InnerComponent extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.exampleMethod = this.exampleMethod.bind(this);
       }

       exampleMethod(){

       }
    }

export default withRouter(InnerComponent , { withRef: true });
```

and also try the below method to access the methods using reference

```
this.myRef.getWrappedInstance().exampleMethod()
```

Comment: Still getting the following error: `Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.` Given the error, I think using the ref in your second part will crash the app.

Comment: That's a different error, and it's self explanatory. The above example is not an SFC.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to do this:

```
    // InnerComponent.js
    class InnerComponent extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
       }
    }

    export default withRouter(InnerComponent);

    // App.js

    import InnerComponentWithRouter, { InnerComponent } from '/InnerComponent'

    class App extends Component {
        private myRef: InnerComponent|null = null;
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Router>
                    <InnerComponentWithRouter wrappedComponentRef={(r: InnerComponent) => this.myRef = r} />
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified the [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823539) by [@pandaiolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644131/pandaiolo) a bit more. Uses `wrappedComponentRef`, which is already used by `withRouter`

```
function withRouterAndRef(WrappedComponent) {
    const RoutableComponent = withRouter(WrappedComponent);
    const RoutableComponentWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <RoutableComponent {...props} wrappedComponentRef={ref} />
    ));
    const name = WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name;
    RoutableComponentWithRef.displayName = `withRouterAndRef(${name})`;
    return RoutableComponentWithRef;
}
```

Comment: How do you type this using TypeScript?